# xbap fails to load in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, xbap

There is one user who only get a dialogue box and download error when browsing to my xbap application. I've got several other client users without this problem.

What could be causing internet explorer not to be able to display the xbap?

Comment: What does the dialogue box and download error specifically say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the errors state, this sounds like an issue with trust on the client workstation.  Try these troubleshooting steps:

**Wrong version of .net Framework**

Make sure the user's version .net is up to date

**Corrupt installation of .net Framework**

Try re-installing the .net framework on the user's computer.  If that doesn't work, try re-installing IE.

**Enable FullTrust in IE**

Partial trust may be enabled the client may need to grant permission to the application URL or add it as a trusted site.  Alternatively, make sure that the XBAP is deployed with FullTrust.  If this is being deplyed in an intranet environment you can deploy a custom CLR Security policy the modify default permission levels.

Comment: well, it "suddenly" started to work on our clients machine :)

Answer (score 1):

How large is your app? Default cache-limit is 250MB:

Add/change`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\OnlineAppQuotaInKB`, which is a `DWORD` value that expresses the cache size in kilobytes. For example, in order to increase the cache size to 500MB, I would change this value to 512000.